# How to merge two Authentication accounts in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to merge two authentication accounts based off the UID?

I have an app that uses the **signInWithEmailLink** to sign in. I am adding **signInWithPhoneNumber**.

I would like to merge the two accounts and I was hoping to do this based off the UIDs.

To be clear. I am NOT using email address and password but the passwordless email link.

Is this possible and if so, could someone please give me guidance?

Comment: What do you expect the be the final result of such a merger?  Keep in mind that user accounts could have all sorts of data attached to them in various cloud products, or even your own storage keyed off UID.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well my app already handles everything based off the passwordless email link and now that I am adding in the signInWithPhoneNumber I was hoping to merge it with the existing account

Comment: Maybe I am going about this the wrong way

Comment: I think you want to read the documentation about linking a new account provider to an existing account. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: I have read that entire doc. They never address the passwordless email link. They only address Email and Password. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking?hl=en&authuser=0#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account

Comment: That might be something you'll want to explicitly mention in your post (that you are following these docs on *linking* an account, and that this is specifically what you're stuck on because it's not mentioned).  It might be the case that linking in this way is simply not possible, and your best bet is to file a feature request. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact